# Linking URL to multiple Map markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get each marker to direct to the url when clicked.  Markers are dropped sequentially on the map and immediately settle after a brief bouncing animation.  However, clicking each marker returns "webpage not found"?  I don't see why this is the case since each url was saved in the mapUrl array variable.  If an explict url is used, it works i.e

> window.location.href = 'www.amazon.com';

But I have multiple markers, so I need the script to read the urls stored in the mapUrl array. This was suggested:

> google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
>           document.getElementById('goToLocation').innerHTML = 'Will send you to ' + this.url;
>       });

But the syntax after the equal sign doesn't work i.e. the this.url part.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marker animations with <code>setTimeout()</code>
    </title>
    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
        }
        #panel {
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -180px;
            z-index: 5;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #999;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <div id="panel">
        <button id="drop" onclick="drop()">Drop Markers</button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()" ;>

    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

    <script>
        var sacramento = new google.maps.LatLng(38.576725, -121.493715);

        var neighborhoods = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(38.576725, -121.493715),
            new google.maps.LatLng(35.011263, -115.473376),
            new google.maps.LatLng(33.941820, -118.408466)
        ];

        var markers = [];
        var map;
        var mapUrl = [
            'http://www.google.com',
            'http://www.youtube.com',
            'http://maps.amazon.com'
        ];

        function initialize() {

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 5,
                center: sacramento
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
            drop();
        }

        function drop() {
            for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
                addMarker(i);
            }
        }

        function addMarker(iterator) {

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: neighborhoods[iterator],
                map: map,
                draggable: false,
                url: mapUrl[iterator],
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                window.location.href = markers.mapUrl;
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);

            markers.push(marker);

        }

        function toggleBounce() {

            if (markers.getAnimation() != null) {
                markers.setAnimation(null);
            } else {

                markers.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
            }

        }
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, you have a `<div>` in the `<head>`

Comment: You also have javascript errors markers is an array, it doesn't have a setAnimation method.

Comment: @Greg, thank you for the follow up! Removing the div fixed the map not drawing. I'm not a programmer, and so I don't understand what syntax to use to connect the marker array to the click listener event. Could you provide the explict code which would permit opening each marker to the related mapUrl link please? I presumed the window.location.href = markers.mapUrl did this by default.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit confusing, but I think you were pretty close to what you were trying to do.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    window.location.href = markers.mapUrl;;
});
```

Should be:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    window.location.href = this.url;
});
```

And since clicking on a marker is redirecting the page, the second click handler that calls `toggleBounce` is not used/needed.  Here's a cleaned up and working version based on what it seemed you're trying to do. Also moved that `div` from the `head` to the `body` and removed the extra import of the maps API.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marker animations with 'setTimeout()'
    </title>
    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
        }
        #panel {
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -180px;
            z-index: 5;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #999;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()" ;>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="panel">
        <button id="drop" onclick="drop()">Drop Markers</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        var sacramento = new google.maps.LatLng(38.576725, -121.493715);

        var neighborhoods = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(38.576725, -121.493715),
            new google.maps.LatLng(35.011263, -115.473376),
            new google.maps.LatLng(33.941820, -118.408466)
        ];

        var markers = [];
        var map;
        var mapUrl = [
            'http://www.google.com',
            'http://www.youtube.com',
            'http://maps.amazon.com'
        ];

        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 5,
                center: sacramento
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
            drop();
        }

        function drop() {
            for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
                addMarker(i);
            }
        }

        function addMarker(iterator) {

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: neighborhoods[iterator],
                map: map,
                draggable: false,
                url: mapUrl[iterator],
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                window.location.href = this.url;
            });

            markers.push(marker);
        }
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```